# Change threaded inbox view in Thunderbird so that subject lines are the most recent subject in the thread

Tags: email, thunderbird

Currently, when using Thunderbird in threaded view, the subject line for each thread is the subject of the original, root email. I would like to change this so that it is the subject of the most recent email. For example, the following thread

```
*- Original subject
|--> Re: Original subject
|---> New subject
|----> Re: New subject
```

when collapsed displays in the inbox as

```
*- Original subject
```

whereas I would like it to display as

```
*- Re: New subject
```

Despite my best efforts, I cannot find how to change this. Is it possible without editing the source and compiling my own version?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Mozilla Wiki - MailNews:Message Threading](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Message_Threading)

You probably want to set `mail.strict_threading=false`